# Pad AWK columns

Tags: awk

Trying to parse BSD `top` output to show only `PID - COMMAND - MEM` for a specific process;

```
$ top -l 1 | grep -E '%CPU\ |coreaudio'
PID    COMMAND          %CPU TIME     #TH    #WQ #PORTS MEM   PURG
354    com.apple.audio. 0.0  00:00.00 2      1   12     820K  0B
296    com.apple.audio. 0.0  00:00.03 2      1   38     2024K 0B
282    coreaudiod       0.0  03:25.05 94     2   736    21M   0B
```

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to show only column `$1 - $2`

```
$ top -l 1 | grep -E '%CPU\ |coreaudio' | awk {'print $1" -- "$2'}
PID -- COMMAND
354 -- com.apple.audio.
296 -- com.apple.audio.
282 -- coreaudiod
```

Adding a 3th column messes with the 'columns' since the second columns is not being padded;

```
$ top -l 1 | grep -E '%CPU\ |coreaudio' | awk {'print $1" -- "$2" -- "$8'}
PID -- COMMAND -- MEM
354 -- com.apple.audio. -- 820K
296 -- com.apple.audio. -- 2024K
282 -- coreaudiod -- 21M
```

How would I 'pad' the 'column' to keep the 'layout' intact? Or should I use a different tool like [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) ?

Note;

Using `top -l 1` [since I'm on a Mac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147472/339347)

Comment: Do you have `column`?

Comment: Yep, tried piping `awk` columns to `column`, but didn't manage to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad the strings with some "constant" amount of spaces:

```
<<<$input awk '{printf "%-20s %-10s %-4s\n", $1, $2, $8}'
#                         ^^    ^^    ^ field width
#                        ^     ^     ^  left justify
```

You can use `column`:

```
<<<$input awk '{print $1, $2, $8}' | column -t
```

Comment: Thx! Both work great! (After setting second to 20widht ;) )
Any idea if this could be done just like `column -t`, so, 'as small as possible', but with `awk`, without any static numbers?

Comment: No, at least not easy. You can reinvent `column` functionality in `awk` and I've seen scripts that do that (mostly on systems where column is not available)... but that's just reinventing the wheel. It would be simple anyway - just keep each column in a separate array, get maximum length of the elements in each array, and then do `printf  "%-" maximum_legnth_fo_elements_in_array1 "s", array1[i]` for each column. I doubt that would be "smaller".  `as small as possible` - Unix philosophy is one tool does one job. `awk` filters columns. `column` formats output.